# Error running an http request within another (GET and POST)

Tags: python, rest, http, fastapi

I'm getting this error when trying to run the below code:

***requests.exceptions.ConnectionError raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))***

The code works when I remove the 'get_refresh_token' call inside of 'get_order_data'.
I have another API connection that works in a similar manner so I'm currently stuck.

```
def get_order_data(order):
old_refresh_token = open('refresh_token.txt', 'r').read()
new_token = get_refresh_token(old_refresh_token)
print(old_refresh_token)

response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/{}'.format(order),
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(new_token)})
return response.json()


def get_refresh_token(token):
    response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/refresh',
                             headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token),
                                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                             data={'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
                                  'refresh_token': token})

rt_file = open('refresh_token.txt', 'w')
rt_file.write(response.text)
rt_file.close()

return response.text




print(get_order_data('1519385'))
```

Comment: It seems like you can't even establish the connection...is the server reachable? You could try `localhost:8000/docs` in the browser to check if it's running

Comment: @Isabi I can reach the server at localhost:8000/docs. Everything else seems to work just fine except for when I run get_refresh_token inside of get_order_data.

Comment: What does your server log on your terminal/logfile?

Comment: Strangely it doesn't appear to log anything. Nothing shows in the terminal once I run these functions and it errors.

Comment: It means the function for the router is not being called. Is it possible you have another server? already running on that port?

Comment: edited: I don't think so because when I remove the call to "get_refresh_token(old_refresh_token)" and hardcode the token into the .format(new_token) space in header it works just fine

Comment: It's unreadable like. Edit your question please

Comment: edited it sorry about that

Comment: UPDATE: I'm guessing Isabi was correct. I came back after a few days and a computer reboot and the script runs just fine. I'm not sure where the other server was already running on that port yet but I'll try to dig into it if it happens again. Thanks Isabi